# Why is my `<sec:IfAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN" >` tag ignored?

Tags: spring-security, facelets

I find that the tag `<sec:IfAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN" >` is ignored and on the `.xhtml` page I am getting the following message:

```
The attribute **roles** is not defined in Component's interface
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard Spring Security taglib does not work with JSF.

You can use [the Facelets version](http://www.ohloh.net/p/spring-security-facelets-taglib).

Then you can use the `sec:ifAnyGranted()` function (not tag) inside an expression:

```
<p:menubar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags">
...
<p:submenu label="#{msgs['menu.report']}" 
                    rendered="#{sec:ifAnyGranted('ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_REPORTER')}">
```

This is a piece of working code that shows a menu only for the given use. 
Note that I do not use [the default Spring JSP taglib](http://www.springframework.org/security/tags) but the Facelets version.